In a two-sided document, changing the page counter messes up the two-sided-ness
I'm creating a two-sided document. The front matter is in roman numerals (\pagenumbering{roman}), and the main matter is in arabic numerals (\pagenumbering{arabic}, resetting the \pagecounter to 1). The problem I'm having is that, because the front matter is currently an odd number of pages in length, both the last page of the front matter and the first page of the main matter have odd page numbers. LaTeX seems to interpret this as them both being odd pages, so my alternating margins and headers get messed up.
Is there a way to fix this? This seems like an obvious bug for two-sided documents, so surely there is a good fix?
Ideally I don't want to insert a blank page, as I don't like the look of it. Also, if my front matter were to change to an even number of pages, then an inserted blank page would cause the issue to reappear.

Odd numbered pages should always be right pages. I've never seen a book, where left pages are numbered with odd page numbers. So you always should use \cleardoublepage before \pagenumbering{…} to add an empty page if needed.

obviously you need a blank page to preserve twoside. in a twoside document "right hand page" just means odd page number and "left side page" means even page number.

your last statement seems false. \cleardoublepage will only force a blank page if needed. If your front matter changes then it would not have a blank page following.

@DavidCarlisle Maybe Jonny doesn't know \cleardoublepage …

Thanks both. I guess if convention dictates the main matter should begin on the right page after a blank page then so be it. @cabohah yes I'd say that question is in esscence the same as mine - I couldn't find it when searching! Correct I didn't know about \cleardoublepage.

BTW: If you use a book class, just use \frontmatter and \mainmatter. In this case you won't need \cleardoublepage or \pagenumbering{…}.

I tried those commands but they didn't work. I'm using a twoside report class, perhaps they don't exist in that class? Perhaps I should use a book class instead, not sure why I didn't pick that originally...

After using \cleardoublepage to insert the blank page, I don't like how the fancy header is continued on the clear page. I tried to use \thispagestyle{empty/plain} both immediately before and after, but to no avail. Do you know how I can handle this?

report isn't a book class. book would be suitable.

This is a new question (and AFAIK also already answered). For example class scrbook (or scrreprt) provide an option for it. With the standard classes, you could use \usepackage[cleardoublepage=empty]{scrextend}. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about the option, the classes and the package.
